# UITextField in UITableView cell becomeFirstResponder programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, cell, becomefirstresponder

I have a `UITextField` with a tag inside a prototype cell. The `UITextField` is set to become first responder when the `UITableView` is being built and a `UISwitch` in the cell above is turned on.
This works if the app starts from scratch or if it was closed and restarted. Once it's loaded the `[tableView reloadData]` doesn't trigger the `becomeFirstResponder` anymore.

If the `UITextField` becomes first responder by touching the textfield later on, I can trigger the `becomeFirstResponder` event with buttons, with pop ups,...
But not with my switch any more.

Any pointers as to what I can try?

Currently, I use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to trigger a pop up. A nice side effect is, that when I pull up the number keypad, I can provide an ok and cancel button within the pop up instead of having to fiddle with separate buttons on the keypad. But it just seems so obviously to be a workaround.

This is how I call firstresponder when building the `UITableView` (which works every time the app starts from scratch):

```
if ([settings doubleForKey:@"limitDouble"]==0 && [settings boolForKey:@"limitBool"]==YES) {
    [dailyLimitEntry becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

dailyLimitEntry is a `UITextField` which is strong so it stays around.

Just for fun I added a button and connected it to my code like this:

```
UITextField *tmp = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:35];
[tmp becomeFirstResponder];
```

This works, too. When I use it with the switch, it's only called once the app is freshly loaded in the memory. Otherwise, my `UITextField` doesn't respond to the switch.

After the first comments, I found a method to check whether or not the `UITableView` has finished reloading

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[settingsTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        //end of loading
        //for example [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        NSLog(@"finished reload");
        NSLog(@"%@",dailyLimitEntry);
        if ([settings boolForKey:@"limitBool"]==YES) {
            UITextField *tmp = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:35];
            [tmp becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Fun thing though is, become first responder is only triggered the first time the switch is used after the app loaded. Initially, the switch is off. So the cell containing the `UITextField` is not drawn yet. Once I switch to `ON`, the `UITextField` gets drawn in the second cell and becomes first responder. If I switch `OFF` and `ON` again, I still get my log "finished reload", but the `UITextField` doesn't become first responder. It's driving me nuts....
Must be  something about the life cycle of the app.

Comment: please show the code where you call `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: Do you have a method that is called when you toggle your switch?  If yes, post that code.  If not, then you need to set that up so that you call becomeFirstResponder when the switch is turned on.

Comment: I have used the same code as in the button example with a switchvalue changed event.

Comment: With the button working, I think it's a matter of timing. Is there some call where I can check whether or not the tableview has reloaded the data? I think it comes from the switch being operated, which calls for the tabledata to reload and once that's done, I can set focus on the textfield.

Comment: my guess is that willDisplayCell and becomeFirstResponder are two methods that'll try to run on the main thread, and the tableView method gets higher priority while the becomeFirstResponder message gets discarded. Try delaying the call to [tmp becomeFirstResponder]; by using performSelector: afterDelay:

Answer (score 2):

Rather than checking the indexPath, check the cell's class.

Here's what I do to bring up the keyboard for a title cell that's blank (when I create a new item):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[FDSSampleTitleCell class]]) {
        FDSSampleTitleCell *titleCell = (FDSSampleTitleCell *)cell;
        if (titleCell.titleField.text.length == 0) {
            [titleCell.titleField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```